# Which software do you use for Scrum?

Tags: agile, process, scrum

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Scrum Software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153260/scrum-software)
>   [Recommendations for project management software for Scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426458/recommendations-for-project-management-software-for-scrum)

I checked wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)

But I am still looking for some insight from the genius minds using SO. I installed Microsoft Project 2010, and was assuming that it would have some template/plugin that would support Scrum. Unfortunately, I couldn't find one :-(

Comment: **This** looks like a discussion (some posters will understand me) or a poll and should be at least marked CW.

Comment: @Pascal: I agree that the title is worded as a discussion. However, what I answered was the implicit question: "Microsoft Project 2010 does not have Scrum support. What does?" Also, as I ask everyone I see suggesting CW: "Please say why you believe that CW is appropriate for this question".

Comment: @John Because this question a poll, it belongs to the community.

Comment: @Pascal: have you read the FAQ yet? CW is meant to permit the Community to _edit_ everyone's posts. There's even some controversy about whether CW is appropriate for polls, since it turns out that nobody uses them to edit other answers in a poll.

Comment: @John Yes I did but honestly, it doesn't help much IMO and there is just **no** clear consensus with CW (as shown by my example with polls), CW is a big mess/failure. But I don't want to discuss CW here (as you said, that's not the right place anyway) and you're actually eluding my main point (giving an answer to an "implicit question" doesn't make the question less discussion or poll oriented).

Comment: @Pascal: it's all a matter of taste. For instance, I note that the question has not actually gone out of control or become a poll, at least not one of those answered by 10 people! If it did, then I would reconsider closing it.

Comment: @John Oh. I didn't notice that the question where we initiated this discussion was out of control (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438418/agile-development-developer-qualification-required-and-disadvantages-of). And while this question is not out of control (because not popular), it's still an open question and thus not appropriate. So, as you said, this is a matter of taste i.e subjective which is exactly the problem: rules shouldn't be subjective. So this will be an endless discussion (and I don't really want to spend more time on it).

Comment: @Pascal: take it to meta. This has been discussed since day 1.

Comment: @Pascal @John @All It is of course also a dupe many times over - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153260/scrum-software for example, and there are lots more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using scrumworks for more than a year. I really like it, the scrum board is pretty and intuitive with drag and drop, support mutiple teams etc. Not very expensive too.

I tried using Microsoft project for many years but given up because if wasn't flexible enough and I now use a mix of scrumworks, excel sheets and a bug database.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend not using any software to start with.  Sticky notes or 3X5 cards on a corkboard/whiteboard are a better way to start.

Focus on the differences in process, understanding the system, and what you're getting out of it first, not the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a Scrum project template for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010. I suggest you download the RC of VSTS and of TFS, install them and find out.

Microsoft Project pretty much just does project management. VSTS is where the developers, testers, project managers and other stakeholders will live.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the Scrum for Team System templates:
http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx